# Parse multiple similar field values from XML file with Python Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to parse an `xml` file with regular expression.
Whichever script tag has "catch" alias, I need to collect "type" and "value".

```
<script type="abc">
    <line x="word" size="1" alias="catch" value="4" desc="description"/>
</script>
<script type="xyz">
    <line x="state" size="5" alias="catch" value="8" desc="description"/>
</script>
```

I tried this regular expression with `multiline` and `dotall`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'script\s+type=\"(\w+)\".*alias=\"catch\"\s+value=\"(\d+)\"', a, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

Output which I am getting is:

```
[('abc', '8')]
```

Expected output is:

```
[('abc', '4'), ('xyz', '8')]
```

Can someone help me in figuring out what I am missing here?

Comment: Don't prase xml with regex. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for an explaination why.

Comment: I dint quite follow why I shouldn't be using regex in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You can parse through the tags and, with a little bit of data re-structuring, easily check for the right `alias` values and store the related attributes of interest.  Like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

to_keep = []
for script in soup.find_all("script"):
    t = script["type"]
    attrs = {
        k:v for k, v in [attr.split("=") 
                         for attr in script.contents[0].split() 
                         if "=" in attr]
    }
    if attrs["alias"] == '"catch"':
        to_keep.append({"type": t, "value": attrs["value"]})

to_keep
# [{'type': 'abc', 'value': '"4"'}, {'type': 'xyz', 'value': '"8"'}]
```

Data:

```
data = """<script type="abc">
    <line x="word" size="1" alias="catch" value="4" desc="description"/>
</script>
<script type="xyz">
    <line x="state" size="5" alias="catch" value="8" desc="description"/>
</script>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Thanks downvoter. I don't think there was any need to downvote this question.

```
>>> re.findall(r'script\s+type=\"(\w+)\".*?alias=\"catch\"\s+value=\"(\d+)\".*?\<\/script\>', a, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
[('abc', '4'), ('xyz', '8')]
```